# Show Equivalence of Binary Quadratic Forms

Tags: number-theory, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I've been stuck on these two problems from my problem set for quite a while.  Any help would be appreciated!

2)Suppose that $ax^2 + bxy + xy^2$ is equivalent to $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2$. Show that $gcd (a, b, c) = gcd (A, B, C)$?

3)Let $f(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ be a positive semidefinite quadratic form of discriminant 0. Put $g = gcd (a, b, c)$. Show that f is equivalent to the form $gx^2$.

Comment: what book are you using? And, in case I do not know the book, are you comfortable writing equivalence using matrices?

Comment: I am using The Theory of Numbers by Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery.  And yes I am.

Comment: alright, pages 162-163 in my edition, exercises 11,12. The symmetric matrices $F,G$ on page 158 are often called Gram matrices. Everything needed is in relation (3.8) on the same page, equivalent iff $M^t FM = G $ with $M$ in the modular group. Suggest you do exercises 3, 4, 7, really, really carefully.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion!  I will be sure to follow up in a couple hours once I know that material beter

Comment: by any chance, do you know how they derived the equations on top of 158?  I have a feeling its very obvious, by for some reason i can't figure it out.  The 3.7 ones.

Comment: As I thought. the (3.7's) at the top of p.158 are precisely what happens if you write out (3.8) using the displayed Gram matrices $F,G$ with the entries of $M$ (modular group) given by usual row-column subscripts as $m_{ij}$